# how to write method that implements on static variable?

Tags: java

I am a newbie to Java. My requirement is to create a program which has static variable ctr. This counter should be incremented when add method is called.create one more static variable which will be decremented every time subtract method is called.

Here is the code I have written: Please suggest next steps for the logic

```
    package com.corejava.stattest;

public class StaticTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(AddSubImpl.addMethod());
        System.out.println(AddSubImpl.subMethod());
    }
}

class AddSubImpl {
    static int ctr = 100;

    public static int addMethod() {
        return ctr = ctr + 1;
    }

    public static int subMethod() {
        return ctr = ctr - 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Answer (score 0):

If `str` is a class field, it does not need to be `static`. Once modified, it will remain so.

Comment: Question is to write methods that will add and subtract static variable value. Did I do it right?

Comment: If it is not `static` it cannot be referenced from the static methods.

Comment: But he never mentioned he will call static methods.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking an open ended question, thus it is hard for people here to answer you anything.

However, looking at your codes. There are a few things you need to look out for.

- You are mixing multiple tasks to your add & subtract method. You should use either a getter or a setter.
- Getters are only responsible of retrieving values. looks like this:

  ```
  public int getValue(){
      return value;
  }
  ```
- Setters for assigning value. It looks like this:

  ```
  public void setValue(int value){
      this.value = value;
  }
  ```
- Why are your add and subtract methods returning values?
- If you don't need them to return values. Your methods shall be void.

First and foremost, do you understand what are static variables? I suggest you to read up on that: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html

---

> create one more static variable which will be decremented every time subtract method is called

You can't create variables at run time.